# Getting specific value from checkbox global array variable in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I created an checkbox using apex_item checkbox and the array APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01 contains the values of selected checkbox  values  .My question how to get the only one specific selected checkbox value from that array . Find my plsql code here and please help me

```
declare
    var_hire DATE ;
    tenure_dt DATE;
    i number ;
BEGIN
    FOR I IN 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.count LOOP
        SELECT HIREDATE INTO var_hire from employee where empno=APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(1);
        SELECT var_hire+ INTERVAL '1' YEAR INTO  tenure_dt FROM DUAL;
             IF SYSDATE < to_Date(tenure_dt,'DD-MON-YY') THEN
                HTP.P('The employee cannot be deleted');    
             END IF ;
    END LOOP ;
END;
```

New PLSQL CODE

```
 declare
    l_index number;
    var_hire DATE ;
    tenure_dt DATE;
begin
    for i in 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.count loop
     if(APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.exists(i)) then  
         SELECT HIREDATE INTO var_hire from employee where empno=APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(i);
         SELECT var_hire+ INTERVAL '1' YEAR INTO  tenure_dt FROM DUAL;
         IF SYSDATE < to_Date(tenure_dt,'DD-MON-YY') THEN
              HTP.P('The employee cannot be deleted');    
         END IF ;
     end if ;
    end loop;
 end ;
```

Comment: You may be encountering this https://roelhartman.blogspot.com/2018/02/apexapplicationgf0x-array-processing-in.html

Comment: Scott its not working and find my updated PLSQL CODE

Comment: The link that Raghu provided should be helpful, but you don't seem to have really understood it. If you're using g_f01 as your checkbox, then it is an array that contains the values for the selected rows. Everything else was an array with one row for every row on the page. So the checkbox array will likely have fewer elements than the other arrays. You need to loop over the checkbox array values and locate the correct index in the other arrays to get the right values. This is why Roel's example has a hidden array with the same values as the checkbox (empno). Think of that as a mapping array.

Comment: @Dan McGhan thanks its working

Answer (score 0):

> APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01 contains the values of selected checkbox values

That's not what your query suggests:

```
where empno = APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(1)
```

`G_F01` is either `empno`, or a checkbox. Can't be both.

If we suppose that `G_F01` really is `empno`, you have to find which one is your checkbox. How? Inspect element in your browser. If it turns out that checkbox is e.g. `G_F05`, then you're missing another condition which checks checkbox' value, e.g.

```
where empno = APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(1)
  and APEX_APPLICATION.G_F05 = 1             --> this
```

and then do *something* with that information.

Comment: Littilefoot its not working and find my updated PLSQL CODE

Comment: Littlefoot checKbox is G_F01

Comment: Could you give us a simplified version of your form's SQL query so we can see the apex_items you've used?  It's possible one of them changed which array is used.

Comment: Congrats. Thanks for taking the time to respond.